# promise catch does not parse json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-http

I'm using Angular `Http` to post to my API, when the status of the response is 200 it parses it properly and outputs just my response as expected, I handle this withing the first `.then()` on the promise but when my API has an error I throw it with a status of 400 and attempt to handle it via the `.catch()` block.

The issue I'm having is that the `.catch()` doesn't have just my raw json error from my api, it's just undefined. My error response from my API looks something like:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Bad request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "IN_USE",
            "message": "Email is in use",
            "field": "email"
        }
    ],
    "data": []
}
```

I have ensured that I'm sending `application/json` headers with both a 200 and 400 response so I'm not sure why my typescript code would not be parsing the json on `.catch()`

My Typescript consists of two files `api` and `user`, user just extends api in order to use the `post()` method I created:

api.ts

```
/**
  * POST to the API
  * @param path    Where to go
  * @param params  What to send
*/
public post(path, params): Promise<any> {
  return this.http
    .post(this.apiUrl + path, params)
    .toPromise()
    .then(r => r.json());
}
```

user.ts

```
/**
  * Registers a user and then logs them in via token
  * @param name Users name
  * @param email Users email
  * @param password Users password
*/
register(name: string, email: string, password: string) {
  this.post('/register', {
    access_token: this.accessToken,
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then(r => {
    // This logs the json just fine
    console.log(r);
  })
  .catch(r => {
    // This is undefined
    console.log(r);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Does `r` actually reference an object that has a `.json` function?

Comment: the response looks correct to me; it is valid JSON.

Comment: @Ouroborus My API always returns JSON, just the status is either 200 or 400. I parse it to json on my API class `.then(r => r.json())`. When the status is 400, it gives me no json, just `undefined` but when the api response status is 200 it parses to json just fine.

Comment: If your status code is 400 (or any other error code) then the promise in your post method is not parsed because the `.then(r => r.json());` part is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your request is failling (400 status code), it's not going to pass throug the `then` callback, it will go to the `catch` one, as you don't have any in the `post` method it will bubble to the `register` method catch, as you didn't parse to json it won't be a json.

Try this:

```
public post(path, params): Promise<any> {
  return this.http
    .post(this.apiUrl + path, params)
    .toPromise()
    .then(r => r.json())
    .catch(e => throw new Error(e.json()));
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.errors[0]')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking for status messages in the `.then(r => )` section and then according to the status you can proceed with your logic.

```
register(name: string, email: string, password: string) {
  this.post('/register', {
    access_token: this.accessToken,
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then(r => {
    // This logs the json just fine
   if(r.status == 200){
     console.log(r);
   }
   if(r.status == 400){
     console.log(r);   
    }


  })
  .catch(r => {
    // This is undefined
    console.log(r);
  });
}
```